# Creating an abusive number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, parallel-processing, synchronization

I'm working on an sorting algorithm to show multithread execution named BITONIC, but the way that I find to run it with multhread is creating new objects and working in an static array, but this lead me to an incredible slow sorting, with some debug -- read prints -- I found that I'm creating an abusive number of threads and consequently a great number of objects, I'm thinking that is it that is making it so slow, but I can't really fix the problem, so if u can give me some tips I'll be really thankful.

Bitonic sort is similar to merge, the truly understanding of the algorithm is not really necessary, only knowledge about threads and java

Here I have some attributes for have individuals threads

```
    public static int[] data;

    private int start, end, size;
    private boolean direction;

    private int minimumLength = 1;

    private final boolean Ascending = true, Descending = false;
```

I have 2 constructors, one for first instance, that will set the value from an external allocated vector

```
    public MultiThreadedSorter (int[] originalData)
    {
        data = originalData;

        start = 0;
        end = size = data.length;
        direction = Ascending;

//        minimumLength = data.length / Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        minimumLength = 2;
    }
```

Another one for recursive divisions with new values for each thread

```
private MultiThreadedSorter (int lo, int hi, boolean dir)
{
    start = lo;
    end = hi;
    size = hi-lo;

    direction = dir;
}
```

An sort only for encapsulating purpose

```
    public void Sort() 
            throws InterruptedException
    {   
        BitonicSort(start, end, direction);
    }
```

Here the run override

```
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            BitonicSort(start, end, direction);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MultiThreadedSorter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

An here where i think that the problem is

```
    private void BitonicSort(int _lo, int _hi, boolean dir) 
            throws InterruptedException // join()
    {   

        int length = _hi - _lo;

//        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - CRIADA");
//        System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", _lo, _hi);

        if (length > 1)
        {
//            Show ("SORT", true);

            if (length > minimumLength)
            {
                int mid = length / 2;

                System.out.println("-- left - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                MultiThreadedSorter leftSorterObj = new MultiThreadedSorter(_lo, _lo+mid, Ascending);
                Thread left = new Thread(leftSorterObj);

                left.start(); // i think that the problem is here
                left.join(); // or here

                System.out.println("-- rigth - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
//                System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", _lo+mid, _hi);
                MultiThreadedSorter rightSorterObj = new MultiThreadedSorter(_lo+mid, _hi, Descending);
                Thread right = new Thread(rightSorterObj);

                right.start(); // i think that the problem is here
                right.join(); // or here

//                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - ENDED\n");
            }
            else
            {
                int mid = (length / 2);

                if (mid > 1)
                {
//                    Show ("R1", false);
                    BitonicSort(_lo, mid, Ascending);
//                    Show ("R2", false);
                    BitonicSort(_lo+mid, mid, Ascending);
                }
            }

            BitonicMerge(_lo, _hi, dir);
        }
    }
```

And now I'll post the main and the complete class, only if you want to execute

MAIN:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            int arraySize = (int) Math.pow(2, 7);
            int[] originalData = new int[arraySize];

            int lim = 20;

            for (int i = 0; i < originalData.length; i++)
                originalData[i] = random.nextInt(lim);

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalData));
            System.out.printf("\n");

            MultiThreadedSorter mult = new MultiThreadedSorter(originalData);
            mult.Sort();

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalData));
            System.out.println();
    }
```

MultiThreadedSorter CLASS

```
    public class MultiThreadedSorter //extends BaseBitonicSorter
            implements Runnable
    {
        public static int[] data;

        private int start, end, size;
        private boolean direction;

        private int minimumLength = 1;

        private final boolean Ascending = true, Descending = false;

        public MultiThreadedSorter (int[] originalData)
        {
            data = originalData;

            start = 0;
            end = size = data.length;
            direction = Ascending;

    //        minimumLength = data.length / Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
            minimumLength = 2;
        }

        // Construtor chamados por cada thread antes de iniciar
        private MultiThreadedSorter (int lo, int hi, boolean dir)
        {
            start = lo;
            end = hi;
            size = hi-lo;

            direction = dir;
        }

        public void Show (String msg, boolean r)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + msg);

            if (r)
                System.out.printf("De: %d\tAte: %d\t Dir: %d\n", start, end, direction ? 1 : 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                BitonicSort(start, end, direction);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(MultiThreadedSorter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        public void Sort() 
                throws InterruptedException
        {   
            BitonicSort(start, end, direction);
        }

        private void BitonicSort(int _lo, int _hi, boolean dir) 
                throws InterruptedException // join()
        {   

            int length = _hi - _lo;

    //        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - CRIADA");
    //        System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", _lo, _hi);

            if (length > 1)
            {
    //            Show ("SORT", true);

                if (length > minimumLength)
                {
                    int mid = length / 2;

                    System.out.println("-- left - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    MultiThreadedSorter leftSorterObj = new MultiThreadedSorter(_lo, _lo+mid, Ascending);
                    Thread left = new Thread(leftSorterObj);

                    left.start();
                    left.join();

                    System.out.println("-- rigth - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    //                System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", _lo+mid, _hi);
                    MultiThreadedSorter rightSorterObj = new MultiThreadedSorter(_lo+mid, _hi, Descending);
                    Thread right = new Thread(rightSorterObj);

                    right.start();
                    right.join();

    //                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - ENDED\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    int mid = (length / 2);

                    if (mid > 1)
                    {
    //                    Show ("R1", false);
                        BitonicSort(_lo, mid, Ascending);
    //                    Show ("R2", false);
                        BitonicSort(_lo+mid, mid, Ascending);
                    }
                }

                BitonicMerge(_lo, _hi, dir);
            }
        }

        private void BitonicMerge(int _lo, int _hi, boolean dir) 
                throws InterruptedException // join()
        {
    //        Show ("MERGE", true);

            int length = _hi - _lo;

            if (length > 1)
            {
                if (length > minimumLength)
                {
                    int mid = (length / 2);

                    for (int i = _lo; i < (_lo + mid); i++)
                        Compare(i, (i + mid), dir);

                    MultiThreadedSorter leftMergerObj = new MultiThreadedSorter(_lo, _lo+mid, dir);
                    Thread left = new Thread(leftMergerObj);

                    left.start();
                    left.join();

                    MultiThreadedSorter rightMergerObj = new MultiThreadedSorter(_lo + mid, _hi, dir);
                    Thread right = new Thread(rightMergerObj);

                    right.start();
                    right.join();
                }
                else
                {
                    int mid = (length / 2);

                    for (int i = _lo; i < (_lo + mid); i++)
                        Compare(i, (i + mid), dir);

                    if (mid > 1)
                    {
                        BitonicMerge(_lo, _lo + mid, dir);
                        BitonicMerge(_lo + mid, _hi, dir);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private synchronized void Compare(int src, int dst, boolean dir)
        {
            if (dir == (data[src] > data[dst]))
                Exchange(src, dst);
        }

        protected synchronized void Exchange(int i, int j)
        {
            int temp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[j];
            data[j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this is so slow:

**Problem:** You do not impose any limit to the number of threads the process can create and you are recursively creating threads which can lead to saturation.

**Solution:** Use a thread pool to limit the amount of threads created (each system has a limit amount of threads that can be created) and reduce start time for threads (every-time you use new Thread(Runnable).start() time is spent to create the new thread). Thread pools can be managed with the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface.

**Problem:** more on the concurrency side, your Compare and Exchange methods are blocking execution of all the threads because they are described as `synchronized` and thus can only be run by one thread at a time.

**Solution:** make data `volatile`